# How to determine path/route in AngularJS to indicate current view in menu

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-routing

I'm writing a small AngularJS app that uses Bootstrap. I'm using Boostraps Nav component and I want to highlight the current page's menu item.

I need to be able to determine the path/route associated with the current view so I can set the CSS class for my Boostrap Nav links.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li data-ng-class="{'active': true}">
        <a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only" data-ng-show="false">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li data-ng-class="{'active': false}">
        <a href="#/about">About Us <span class="sr-only" data-ng-show="false">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li data-ng-class="{'active': false}">
        <a href="#/services">Services <span class="sr-only" data-ng-show="false">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li data-ng-class="{'active': false}">
        <a href="#/testimonials">Testimonials <span class="sr-only" data-ng-show="false">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li data-ng-class="{'active': false}">
        <a href="#/contact">Contact <span class="sr-only" data-ng-show="false">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to replace the "true/false" values in the data-ng-class of the LI elements to be an expression that evaluates to true when LI matches the currently displayed view, and also data-ng-show evaluates to true under the same circumstances.

Is that the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any other way to achieve that. Following is the tentative code.

Add a function say `isActive()` in your controller as follows,

```
$scope.isActive = function (route) {
    return route === $location.path();
};
```

In your HTML, replace the `true/false` value with the function in `ng-class` as follows,

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <!-- use the `isActive()` function here in `ng-class` -->
    <li data-ng-class="{'active': isActive('/')}">
        <a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only" data-ng-show="false">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
   <li data-ng-class="{'active': isActive('/about')}">
       <a href="#/about">About Us <span class="sr-only" data-ng-show="false">(current)</span></a>
    </li>

    ...
</ul>
```

Once please check what is `$location.path()` is returning in the controller and change the argument value for `isActive()` function in the HTML code. It will change depending whether you are using `html5` mode or not (include `#` or not).

Comment: This makes sense, however I am seeing that location.path is always returning an empty string.  Not sure what you meant by using HTML5 mode...I am using HTML5 for this project.

Comment: Is it returning an empty string for all the routes? Like `#/about`, `#/contact` etc? Regarding the `html5` mode, check this link. Search for _hashbang_ or _html5 mode_ https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Comment: I needed to remove the leading "#" character, it works now.  Thanks

Comment: Great! So you meant something like `isActive('/about')`?

Comment: That's it exactly.